# jQuery eq() selects too many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removechild

I'm removing a div according to which close button the user clicks, so I'm using eq (), the problem is that for example the user clicks on eq (0), the first one says some (as expected), but the second div is also considered eq (0) and some. It is as if for example I close the div eq (0) the other two divs also close, as if they were eq (0), but this all with just a click on the div eq (0) for example that was to close only one, I've already tried using stopImmediatePropagation (), but when I close a div it closes all of the above, and when I do not use it all shuts down! Anyone know what the problem is?

Here is an example of the eq () code:

```
$('.' + tabHistoryBtn).click(function() { //close button
            var index = $(this).index();
            if(index == 0){
                $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(0).remove(); //content to remove
                $('.' + tabHistory).eq(0).remove();
                if(currentbtn == "home"){
                    countContentHome = countContentHome -1;
                }if(currentbtn == "explore"){
                    countContentExplore = countContentExplore -1;
                }
                alert("1");
            }
            if(index == 1){
                $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(1).remove();
                $('.' + tabHistory).eq(1).remove();
                if(currentbtn == "home"){
                    countContentHome = countContentHome -1;
                }if(currentbtn == "explore"){
                    countContentExplore = countContentExplore -1;
                }
                alert("2");
            }
            if(index == 2){
                $('.' + currentDivTabBarContent).eq(2).remove();
                $('.' + tabHistory).eq(2).remove();
                if(currentbtn == "home"){
                    countContentHome = countContentHome -1;
                }if(currentbtn == "explore"){
                    countContentExplore = countContentExplore -1;
                }
                alert("3");
            }
});
```

Here is the Jsfiddle with the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/willianjohns/w5eLs8d4/16/

Comment: What's the point of repeating same code 3 times?

Comment: I tried to implement a system that identifies if you click the first close button, close the first content and the first tab, and so on!

Comment: If you click `index`th button, you close `index`th tab, isn't it?

Comment: The close button is the child of the tab, and the content to be closed is in another div, when clicked on the close button, removes the tab that is the button and the contents of another div

Comment: `$('.' + tabHistory).eq(INDEX).remove();` see how you should use `index`, got it?

Comment: You have *TONS* of duplicate code. If you need a bunch of lines elsewhere, too, *do not* copy and paste them over. Learn how to use functions, and you will make it much easier for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var index = $(this).index();` always returns 0. Replacing that with `$('.' + tabHistoryBtn).index(this)` will do what you're expecting.

http://api.jquery.com/index has more information on how to use $.index()